# Exclude generated-sources from code coverage without impacting overall code-coverage

Tags: java, sonarqube, code-coverage, jacoco, sonarqube-scan

I have a project for which the code coverage numbers are pretty low. After doing a deep-dive I found out the jacoco code-coverage stats are depending on target directoy instead of src.

```
target/generated-sources/delombok/com/
```

If I exclude the target directory the coverage goes down 0%. So isnt code-coverage supposed to be measured against the code (src) rather than the target folder. Below is the screenshot from SonarQube.

[image]

So the question is how do i make sure the code coverage is measured for src instead of target?

Following is the pom without dependencies:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>removed</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxxx</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.11-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>



    <build>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cassandra-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.7-1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <script>${basedir}/src/main/cassandra/local_run.cql</script>
                    <cqlVersion>3.2.0</cqlVersion>
                    <startNativeTransport>true</startNativeTransport>
                    <nativeTransportPort>9142</nativeTransportPort>
                    <jmxPort>17199</jmxPort>
                    <storagePort>17000</storagePort>
                    <loadFailureIgnore>false</loadFailureIgnore>
                    <cuLoadFailureIgnore>false</cuLoadFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>start</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                            <goal>load</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase> <!--Bind cassandra start and load to process-classes which is the phase that is called up before tomcat is run -->
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>stop</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <!--Bind cassandra stop to generate-test-sources which is the phase that is called up before
                        tests are run. This is because our tests start their own cassandra -->
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                        <version>1.7.7</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <!--Needed to add this so that src/main/java is recognized as a source folder -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Unit Test -->


            <!-- Integration Test -->


            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>activationloginedge</warName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Tomcat Integration Test -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/activationloginedge</path>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>tomcat-run</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <systemProperties>
                                <!-- We want test configuration for running integration tests. -->
                                <archaius.deployment.environment>test</archaius.deployment.environment>
                                <logback-lib.env>filesystem</logback-lib.env>
                            </systemProperties>
                            <fork>true</fork>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>tomcat-shutdown</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shutdown</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        <plugin>
      <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
      <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>0.7.4.201502262128</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>pre-unit-test</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
          <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
             <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-ut.exec</destFile>
             <!-- Sets the name of the property containing the settings for JaCoCo runtime agent.-->
             <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
        <!--Ensures that the code coverage report for unit tests is created after unit tests have been run.-->
        <execution>
          <id>post-unit-test</id>
          <phase>test</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>report</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
          <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
          <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-ut.exec</dataFile>
          <!-- Sets the output directory for the code coverage report. -->
          <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
          </configuration>
</execution>        <execution>
<id>pre-integration-test</id>
<phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
<goals>
    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
</goals>
<configuration>
<!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
    <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-it.exec</destFile>
    <!-- Sets the name of the property containing the settings for JaCoCo runtime agent.-->
    <propertyName>failsafeArgLine</propertyName>
 <

    /configuration>
    </execution>
    <!--   Ensures that the code coverage report for integration tests after  integration tests have been run.-->
    <execution>
        <id>post-integration-test</id>
        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
        </goals>
     <configuration>
    <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
    <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</dataFile>
     <!-- Sets the output directory for the code coverage report. -->
            <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-it</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
     </execution>
     </executions>
     </plugin>
    <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.12.4</version>
       <configuration>
         <!-- Sets the VM argument line used when unit tests are run. -->
         <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
         <!-- Skips unit tests if the value of skip.unit.tests property is true -->
         <skipTests>${skip.unit.tests}</skipTests>
         <!-- Excludes integration tests when unit tests are run. -->
         <excludes>
           <exclude>**/IT*.java</exclude>
         </excludes>
       </configuration>
      </plugin>
    <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.15</version>      <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
          <configuration>
         <!-- Sets the VM argument line used when integration tests are run-->
             <argLine>${failsafeArgLine}</argLine>
         <!-- Skips integration tests if the value of skip.integration.tests property is true-->
            <skipTests>${skip.integration.tests}</skipTests>      </configuration>
              </execution>
              </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

Comment: Can you please give more details about your configuration? Indeed, code coverage is computed against source code, so looks like you configured "target" to be one of the source folders.

Comment: Attached the pom by removing the dependency section

Comment: Uhhh, looks like you forgot to attach (or give a link to) the file @Jeel

Comment: sorry forgot to save the edit for adding the pom. It is now added above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the Lombok Maven plugin modifies the list of source folders during the Maven build, this is why the `target/generated-sources/delombok` folder is recognized by SonarQube as a source folder.

In order to force SonarQube to consider only your own source files, you should add the following property to your POM:

```
<properties>
  <sonar.sources>src/main/java</sonar.sources>
</properties>
```

This will solve your problem.